# OpenCV 2.4.2 with QT

Tags: windows, qt, opencv

HelloI'm actually stuck with utilisation of OpenCV 2.4.2 and QT.

I can compile my project, but when i run it through QT, i've not the good windws.

I run QTCreator last version under Windows

Here what i did to use OpenCV 2.4.2 with QT :

1. Download OpenCV and extract it to C:/
2. Install MinGW and add path variable
3. Modify my .pro file like this :

   TEMPLATE = app

   CONFIG += console

   CONFIG -= qt

   INCLUDEPATH = C:\Users\Erowlin\Desktop\OpenCv_QT\opencv\include

   LIBS = -LC:\Users\Erowlin\Desktop\OpenCv_QT\opencv\lib -l opencv_core242 -l opencv_highgui242

   SOURCES += main.cpp

I actually can compile with no error, but when i run my program, i got this Window : [image]

When i execute my program manually, i've no problem, everything work like a charm.

Someone already got the same problem?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is how your .pro file looks like....

```
INCLUDEPATH += C:\Users\Erowlin\Desktop\OpenCv_QT\opencv\build\include 

LIBS +=-LC:\Users\Erowlin\Desktop\OpenCv_QT\opencv\build\x86\mingw\lib\ 
-lopencv_core242\ 
-lopencv_highgui242\ 
-lopencv_imgproc242\ 
-lopencv_video242\
```

and your system variable named path should have

1. C:\Users\Erowlin\Desktop\OpenCv_QT\opencv\build\x86\vc9\bin (if you have Qt 4.8.1 for desktop MSVC2008 (QtSDK) Debug as your target)
2. C:\Users\Erowlin\Desktop\OpenCv_QT\opencv\build\x86\mingw\bin (if your target is based on Qt MinGW x86 )
3. C:\Users\Erowlin\Desktop\OpenCv_QT\opencv\build\common\tbb\ia32\vc9(mingw) (i have added this coz it was showing some weird errors...u can try it)

after editing the path variable close the Qt ide/application and restart it for the system variable change to get reflected..

try to get the opencv 2.4.2 from [this website](http://opencv.org/)...use the already built libraries and dll or use CMAKE to build from scratch...i also faced problem reading image using the cv::Mat format with imread and imshow ...but downloading the opencv2.4.2 from the opencv.org solved the problem...if still not solved then  try linking the debug libraries like opencv_core242d.lib...it mite solve the problem..